# The difference way to implement the learning rate scheduling in TensorFlow 2.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to implement my learning scheduler in TensorFlow, but it seem there are two method to do. First is to use *tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule* and the other is *tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler*. The second method can run successful.

Also, I write a callback to save the learning rate in each epoch, but it crushes if *model.fit(verbose=1)* and *verbose = 0* is good. What is the difference between two methods, and how can I fix it?

Python interpreter: 3.9.13

TensorFlow: 2.10.0 (run on [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit))

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioSSw.png)

```
step_size = 10
base_lr = 0.00005
max_lr = 0.0005
cyclic_decay = 0.75

class LR_History(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs['learning_rate'] = self.model.optimizer.lr.numpy()

def CyclicLR(epoch, lr):
    cycle = tf.floor(1 + epoch / (2 * step_size))
    x = tf.abs((epoch / step_size) - (2 * cycle) + 1)
    lr = base_lr + (max_lr - base_lr) # * tf.math.maximum(0, (1 - x)) * float(cyclic_decay ** (cycle - 1))

    return lr

class MyRSchedule(tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):

    def __init__(self, initial_learning_rate):
        self.initial_learning_rate = tf.cast(initial_learning_rate, dtype=tf.float32)

    def __call__(self, step):
        #return self.initial_learning_rate / (step + 1)
        return CyclicLR(step, self.initial_learning_rate)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'initial_learning_rate': self.initial_learning_rate
        })
        return config

# First method
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=MyRSchedule(0.9)),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

train_history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=50, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, lr_history])

# The second method

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.9),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
train_history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=50, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, lr_history, CyclicLR])
```

I write a callback to save the learning rate in each epoch, but it crushes if *model.fit(verbose=1)* and *verbose = 0* is good. What is the difference between two methods, and how can I fix it?